# Custom html page for QUnit test, run with Resharper

Tags: resharper, qunit, chutzpah

Whenever we do kind of integration testing, where our js tests manipulate DOM, we create an html-page with all required DOM-elements, and after that in `<script>`-tags we define QUnit tests.

Such tests (inside html-files) are not recognized by Resharper runner (it only recognizes QUnit tests inside js-files). We use Chutzpah runner to run QUnit tests which are defined in html-files. However having two runners (Resharper and Chutzpah) does not seem acceptable.

How do you usually handle this (i.e. defining custom pieces of DOM for tests, we don't want to use string constants in JS)? The preference is only having Resharper runner.